# PhoneGap - DOM doesn't update after onDeviceReady event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom, cordova

I've a problem with the `onDeviceReady` event in PhoneGap.

When my app starts, I dynamically fill some fields using jQuery.text() and then I start an animated progress bar.

Testing it without listening events (but writing the code in `app.initialize()`), everything works.

Using events, the code behind works, but the DOM doesn't update.

I tried to use this jQuery code line: `$('.page').trigger('refresh');`
and it worked fine, except for the animated progress bar.

Is `jQuery.trigger('refresh')` a clean solution? (I think no!)

How could I solve this problem?

Thank you!

---

Here's the code:

```
var app = {

    dateP: "",

    initialize: function (date) {
        dateP = date;
        //this.actions();
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function () {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

    receivedEvent: function (id) {
        if (id == 'deviceready') this.actions();
    },

    actions: function () {

        var date = this.getDate();

        var id = this.getDayId(date);
        var perc = Math.ceil((id / 365) * 100);

        this.shareButtonInizialize();
        this.fillDivs(new Date());

        $("#mainDayCounter").text("Giorno #" + this.getDayId(date));
        $("#dayCounter").text("Giorno #" + this.getDayId(date));

        this.setBar(perc);
    },

    setBar: function (perc) {
        $("#main-page #probar").attr({
            "data-pro-bar-percent": perc,
                "data-pro-bar-text": perc + "% \xa0"
        });

    },

    /* OTHER FUNCTIONS */

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. is `$("#mainDayCounter").text("Giorno #" + this.getDayId(date));` not updating the DOM?

Comment: yes! this is the problem!

Comment: I solved using the method `$("#mainDayCounter").show()` after setting the text!
Thank you!